# pyqt5 QMdiArea multiple active subwindows

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

In QMdiArea, we can select (point) to the activate subwindow. In my application, I want to select multiple subwindows (maybe using the "Ctrl" button) and set them as active windows (>=2 subwindows) and create a list pointer for them. I am trying to get pointers for more than one subwindow at the same time. Yes, activeSubWindow() gives only one window. But I wonder if I can use somthing like the "Ctrl" button in keyboard to select two subwindows and print the pointers to these subwindows. The idea is to get the widgets inside each subwindow (e.g TextEditor) at the same time to do afterward tasks, e.g., comparison

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMdiArea, QAction, QMdiSubWindow, QTextEdit
import sys
 
 
 
class MDIWindow(QMainWindow):
 
    count = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
 
        self.mdi = QMdiArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mdi)
        bar = self.menuBar()
 
        file = bar.addMenu("File")
        file.addAction("New")
        file.addAction("cascade")
        file.addAction("Tiled")
        file.addAction("selected_subwindows")
        file.triggered[QAction].connect(self.WindowTrig)
        self.setWindowTitle("MDI Application")
 
    def WindowTrig(self, p):
 
 
        if p.text() == "New":
            MDIWindow.count = MDIWindow.count + 1
            sub = QMdiSubWindow()
            sub.setWidget(QTextEdit())
            sub.setWindowTitle("Sub Window" + str(MDIWindow.count))
            self.mdi.addSubWindow(sub)
            sub.show()
 
        if p.text() == "cascade":
            self.mdi.cascadeSubWindows()
 
        if p.text() == "Tiled":
            self.mdi.tileSubWindows()
            
        if p.text()=="selected_subwindows":
            """I want to select multiple subwindows and and set as activate 
                windows with the "Ctrl" button and return a points fot all active windows"""
            print("active windows: ", self.mdi.activeSubWindow())
 
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mdi  =MDIWindow()
mdi.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Sorry but I really don't understand what you're asking: there can ***always*** be just ***one*** active window, even in a MDI area. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to get pointers for more than one subwindow at the same time. Yes, activeSubWindow() gives only one window. But I wonder if I can use somthing like the "Ctrl" button in keyboard to select two subwindows and print the pointers to these subwindows. The idea is to get the widgets inside each subwindow (e.g TextEditor) at the same time to do afterward tasks, e.g., comparison

Comment: Can I get the previous activat subwindow. Like a signal/slot to update a variable when this subwindow is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like with normal window handling, it's not possible to have multiple active sub windows even in an MDI area.

In order to achieve a "multiple selection" system, you need to track the activation state of the sub windows, which can be tricky.
Subwindows can be activated in different ways:

- by clicking on their title bar (including any of its buttons);
- by clicking on its contained widget;
- by programmatically activating it with [`setActiveSubWindow()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdiarea.html#setActiveSubWindow) (which is similar to selecting a normal window from the task bar);

While Qt provides the [`aboutToActivate`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdisubwindow.html#aboutToActivate) signal, it's not always reliable: it is *always* emitted even when the top level window gets focus, so there's no direct way to know the reason of the activation.
The same also goes for the [`windowStateChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdisubwindow.html#windowStateChanged) signal (which is emitted *after* the state has changed).

For your situation, the best approach is mainly based on the `mousePressEvent` implementation of the subwindow, but also considering the window state changes, because you need to keep track of the current active windows whenever the activation is changed in any other way (by clicking on the widget or by using `setActiveSubWindow()`.

Since mouse events are handled *after* the window activation is changed, the proper solution is to create a signal for which the emission will be delayed (scheduled), in order to know if the activation was actually achieved by a mouse button press on the subwindow (not on the child widget) and finally check if the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key was pressed in the meantime.

Please note that the following code is very basic, and you might need to do some adjustments. For instance, it doesn't consider activations for minimized windows (unlike normal windows, a subwindow could be active even if it's minimized), nor considers activations when clicking on any of the window buttons.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys

class SubWindow(QMdiSubWindow):
    activated = pyqtSignal(object, bool)
    ctrlPressed = False
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.windowStateChanged.connect(self.delayActivated)
        self.activatedTimer = QTimer(
            singleShot=True, interval=1, timeout=self.emitActivated)

    def delayActivated(self, oldState, newState):
        # Activation could also be triggered for a previously inactive top
        # level window, but the Ctrl key might still be handled by the child
        # widget, so we should always assume that the key was not pressed; if
        # the activation is done through a mouse press event on the subwindow
        # then the variable will be properly set there.
        # Also, if the window becomes inactive due to programmatic calls but
        # *after* a mouse press event, the variable has to be reset anyway.
        self.ctrlPressed = False
        if newState & Qt.WindowActive:
            self.activatedTimer.start()
        elif not newState and self.activatedTimer.isActive():
            self.activatedTimer.stop()

    def emitActivated(self):
        self.activated.emit(self, self.ctrlPressed)
        self.ctrlPressed = False

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.ctrlPressed = event.modifiers() & Qt.ControlModifier
            self.activatedTimer.start()
        super().mousePressEvent(event)


class MDIWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("MDI Application")

        self.activeWindows = []
        activeContainer = QWidget()
        activeLayout = QVBoxLayout(activeContainer)
        activeLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.activeList = QListWidget()
        # Note: the following "monkey patch" is only for educational purposes
        # and done in order to keep the code short, you should *not* normally
        # do this unless you really know what you're doing.
        self.activeList.sizeHint = lambda: QSize(150, 256)
        activeLayout.addWidget(self.activeList)

        self.compareBtn = QPushButton('Compare', enabled=False)
        activeLayout.addWidget(self.compareBtn)

        self.activeDock = QDockWidget('Selected windows')
        self.activeDock.setWidget(activeContainer)
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, self.activeDock)
        self.activeDock.setFeatures(self.activeDock.NoDockWidgetFeatures)

        self.mdi = QMdiArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mdi)
        bar = self.menuBar()

        fileMenu = bar.addMenu("File")
        self.newAction = fileMenu.addAction("New")
        self.cascadeAction = fileMenu.addAction("Cascade")
        self.tileAction = fileMenu.addAction("Tiled")
        self.compareAction = fileMenu.addAction("Compare subwindows")

        fileMenu.triggered.connect(self.menuTrigger)
        self.compareBtn.clicked.connect(self.compare)

    def menuTrigger(self, action):
        if action == self.newAction:
            windowList = self.mdi.subWindowList()
            if windowList:
                count = windowList[-1].index + 1
            else:
                count = 1
            sub = SubWindow()
            sub.index = count
            sub.setWidget(QTextEdit())
            sub.setWindowTitle("Sub Window " + str(count))
            self.mdi.addSubWindow(sub)
            sub.show()
            sub.activated.connect(self.windowActivated)
 
        elif action == self.cascadeAction:
            self.mdi.cascadeSubWindows()
 
        elif action == self.tileAction:
            self.mdi.tileSubWindows()
            
        elif action == self.compareAction:
            self.compare()

    def windowActivated(self, win, ctrlPressed):
        if not ctrlPressed:
            self.activeWindows.clear()
        if win in self.activeWindows:
            self.activeWindows.remove(win)
        self.activeWindows.append(win)
        self.activeList.clear()
        self.activeList.addItems([w.windowTitle() for w in self.activeWindows])
        valid = len(self.activeWindows) >= 2
        self.compareBtn.setEnabled(valid)
        self.compareAction.setEnabled(valid)

    def compare(self):
        editors = [w.widget() for w in self.activeWindows]
        if len(editors) < 2:
            return
        it = iter(editors)
        oldEditor = next(it)
        while True:
            try:
                editor = next(it)
            except:
                msg = 'Documents are equal!'
                break
            if oldEditor.toPlainText() != editor.toPlainText():
                msg = 'Documents do not match!'
                break
            oldEditor = editor
        QMessageBox.information(self, 'Comparison result', msg, QMessageBox.Ok)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mdi = MDIWindow()
mdi.show()
app.exec_()
```

Note that I had to make some further changes to your code:

- action checking should ***never*** be done by string comparison: the style or localization could potentially add mnemonics or text variations to action texts, and you'll never get your action triggered: create proper instance attributes and verify the action by object comparison instead.
- the `count` must be an *instance* attribute, not a class one: if, for any reason, you have to create multiple instances of the main window, you'll get an inconsistent count; you should also consider the currently existing windows;
- you should not specify signal overloads if there are no overloads at all (which is the case of `QMenu.triggered`) nor create local variables if they are being used only once (and their names are not that long, like `self.menuBar()`);

Comment: Thanks a lot for the elaboration. I had my solution of using FocusInEvent, but your answer is superior. Thanks for your contributions

Comment: You're welcome! Using FocusIn is not sufficient, as windows get selected even when the widget is focused, but without receiving the focus event, which would make the selection inconsistent.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I faced this issue and I could't solve it